# Python+ Selenium+ RobotFramework Issue

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I'm using `Mac OS X 10.10.5`, `selenium 2.53.6`, `python 2.7.10`, `Firefox Version 47.0.1`. While running the tests using pycharm.

I am getting error

> WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir:
>   /var/folders/v/v/v/v/webdriver-py-profilecopy If you specified a
>   log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details

Firefox opens, but doesn't load the url from mypython script.

Please help out

Thanks

Comment: can you please post some code?

Comment: Thanks @VivekKalyanarangan it started working when I updated selenium to latest